# Git pull gives conflicts with octopus strategy

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, remote-branch

Lately when I run `git pull` in my master branch it occasionally gives the following merge error:

```
   Trying simple merge with 7ff9b5...
   Trying simple merge with 6872cd...
   Simple merge did not work, trying automatic merge.
   Auto-merging file.txt
   ERROR: content conflict in file.txt
   fatal: merge program failed
   Automated merge did not work.
   Should not be doing an Octopus.
   Merge with strategy octopus failed.
```

However after this merge attempt there are files that aren't even in the master branch.
I can fix this issue using `git reset` and pulling again but I was wondering where this head or commits where coming from how can I find this? I tried looking in `gitk` and checking the local GitLab servers but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see an individual file's history with `git log <filename>`. This may help to identify your mystery files.

For conflicts, the source of the conflict [should be shown with the conflict markers](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts):

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:filename
...
=======
...
>>>>>>> abcd123:filename
```

It may also help to switch from a `git pull` workflow to a `git fetch` workflow.

`fetch` updates your remote branch pointer (e.g. `origin/master`) but does not automatically merge your local branch (e.g. `master`). You can then use `gitk --all` to visually compare the branches, `git diff origin/master` to view changes in the terminal, etc.

Once you are satisfied and want to incorporate your upstream changes, all you need to do is merge (e.g. `git merge origin/master` from the `master` branch). Generally, [`git pull` is `git fetch` followed by `git merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).

Comment: The question is how merge from single branch can end with octopus merge?