# Git(Hub) 3 way merge, patch

Tags: git, github, merge, diff, patch

Is there a way to automatically merge (interdiff) conflicts between 2 head branches and 1 base branch?

I was trying to do it at the patch level

- VersionA is my base
- VersionB is branched from VersionA
- VersionB has an additional mod applied, Base+ModB
- VersionC is branched from VersionA
- VersionC has an additional mod applied, Base+ModC

Manually applying patches, I can derive a A:B and a A:C patch, and apply them to version A sequentially.  However, if the two conflict in the areas they apply in (such as editing the same area), they break.

I've tried various tools like interdiff and combinediff to create a combined patch manually to no success (I'm on windows, and interdiff is cygwin compatible, but I don't know if UNC are an issue, so far I don't think so), specificying such as outputs as Unified vs Contextual due to interdiff/combinediff requirements.

So... is there a way I can do a Version A as my Base, and a combined changes of version A:B && A:C as my head?  And do some sort of 3-way pull request?

If any conflicts arise, I would hope git would be able to address them intelligently by doing it's infamous >>>> and ===== and <<<<< merging of conflicts, which is completely acceptable at this point.

Ultimately, I'd like to figure out a way to do this on a patch level by combining patches.  I see that git(hub) has some options for working with 3 way patches and emailing patches with git apply and git patch and git format-patch.

this also helped:
[Git pull gives conflicts with octopus strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905075/git-pull-gives-conflicts-with-octopus-strategy)

Although I'm not pulling from remote and pull is merge when working locally (the command works the exact same pretty much).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest would be an octopus merge (merge of multiple HEADs):

```
git merge B C
```

Note that the order can be important: "[Git octopus merge order of multiple branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6521223/6309)".

---

The [OP thistleknot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1731972/thistleknot) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388806/github-3-way-merge-patch/25398737#comment39633257_25398737):

> The merge didn't work initially until I figured I had branched off a common ancestor at the "wrong point" more or less.
>   I didn't know it until I looked at the `merge*.*` output files and saw each merge file was a source file. One from Version `B` and Version `C` and the common ancestor of `B` and `C`. Once I figured that out, I was able to do some more branching magic, and the merge worked, with the `<<<` and `====`

Comment: thank you, someone else said I should look into that or rebasing.  I appreciate it, I'll try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you.  The merge didn't work initially until I figured I had branched off a common ancestor at the "wrong point" more or less.  I didn't know it until I looked at the merge*.* output files and saw each merge file was a source file.  One from Version B and Version C and the common ancestor of B and C.  Once I figured that out, I was able to do some more branching magic, and the merge worked, with the <<< and ==== :)

Comment: @thistleknot great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.